# HTML5 Geolocation data loaded in a form to send towards database

Tags: forms, html, google-maps, web-applications, geolocation

i'm busy with a school project and I have to build a web app. One function that I want to use is Google Maps and HTML5 Geo Location to pin point what the location of the mobile user is.

I have found this HTML5 Geo Location function on http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation and works very well for me. However, I want the adress data to be placed into a form so that I can submit it to my database when a mobile user Geo locates his position. This causes the marker to be saved and can be viewed on a global website.

Who know how to get the "Your address:" data loaded into a input field of a form?
Below you can find my Html file. Maybe somebody got a better suggestion perhaps?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<title>HTML 5 Geolocation</title>

<style>
#map {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

</style>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1"); google.load("jqueryui", "1");</script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAiUzO1s6QWHuyzxx-JVN7ABSUL8-Cfeleqd6F6deqY-Cw1iTxhxQkovZkaxsxgKCdn1OCYaq7Ubz3SQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.8&appid=n2wY9mzV34Hsdslq6TJoeoJDLmAfzeBamSwJX7jBGLnjM7oDX7fU.Oe91KwUbOwqzvc-"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Geolocation with HTML 5 and Google Maps API based on example from maxheapsize: http://maxheapsize.com/2009/04/11/getting-the-browsers-geolocation-with-html-5/
//
// This script is by Merge Database and Design, http://merged.ca/ -- if you use some, all, or any of this code, please offer a return link.

var map;
var mapCenter
var geocoder;
var fakeLatitude;
var fakeLongitude;

function initialize() 
{   

    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function (position) {  

            // Did we get the position correctly?
            // alert (position.coords.latitude);

            // To see everything available in the position.coords array:
            // for (key in position.coords) {alert(key)}

            mapServiceProvider(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

        }, // next function is the error callback
            function (error)
            {
                switch(error.code) 
                {
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert ('Timeout');
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert ('Position unavailable');
                        break;
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert ('Permission denied');
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        alert ('Unknown error');
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    } 
    else 
    {
      alert("I'm sorry, but geolocation services are not supported by your browser or you do not have a GPS device in your computer. I will use a sample location to produce the map instead.");

      fakeLatitude = 49.273677;
      fakeLongitude = -123.114420;

      //alert(fakeLatitude+', '+fakeLongitude);   
      mapServiceProvider(fakeLatitude,fakeLongitude);
    }  
}

function mapServiceProvider(latitude,longitude)
{
    if (window.location.querystring['serviceProvider']=='Yahoo')
    {
        mapThisYahoo(latitude,longitude);
    }
    else
    {
        mapThisGoogle(latitude,longitude);
    }
}

function mapThisYahoo(latitude,longitude)
{
    var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map'));  
    map.addTypeControl();   
    map.setMapType(YAHOO_MAP_REG);  
    map.drawZoomAndCenter(latitude+','+longitude, 3);

    // add marker
    var currentGeoPoint = new YGeoPoint( latitude, longitude );  
    map.addMarker(currentGeoPoint);

    // Start up a new reverse geocoder for addresses?
    // YAHOO Ajax/JS/Rest API does not yet support reverse geocoding (though they do support it via Actionscript... lame)
    // So we'll have to use Google for the reverse geocoding anyway, though I've left this part of the script just in case Yahoo! does support it and I'm not aware of it yet
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLocations(latitude+','+longitude, addAddressToMap);
}

function mapThisGoogle(latitude,longitude)
{
    var mapCenter = new GLatLng(latitude,longitude);
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(mapCenter, 15);
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(mapCenter));

    // Start up a new reverse geocoder for addresses?
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLocations(latitude+','+longitude, addAddressToMap);
}

function addAddressToMap(response)
{
    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
    } else {
        place = response.Placemark[0];
        $('#address').html('Your address: '+place.address);
    }
}

window.location.querystring = (function() {

    // by Chris O'Brien, prettycode.org
    var collection = {};
    var querystring = window.location.search;
    if (!querystring) {
        return { toString: function() { return ""; } };
    }
    querystring = decodeURI(querystring.substring(1));

    var pairs = querystring.split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {

        if (!pairs[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        var seperatorPosition = pairs[i].indexOf("=");

        if (seperatorPosition == -1) {
            collection[pairs[i]] = "";
        }
        else {
            collection[pairs[i].substring(0, seperatorPosition)] 
                = pairs[i].substr(seperatorPosition + 1);
        }
    }

    collection.toString = function() {
        return "?" + querystring;
    };

    return collection;
})();
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="content">
<div id="map"></div>
<p id="address"></p>

<form id="ContactForm" action="">
                            <p>
                                <label>Topic</label>
                                    <input id="event" name="event" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Address</label>
                                    <input id="address" name="address" maxlength="120" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
                            </p>
                            <input id="send" type="button" value="Send"/>
                            <input id="newcontact" name="newcontact" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
                        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript to set the value of address input field, this way

1- Add name attribute to the form and input.

2-    `document.formName.inputName.value=place.address;`

Good Luck

Comment: Hello Hesham,

Where do I need to place that line of code in my html file?
Thanks

Comment: $('#address').html('Your address: '+place.address); under this line (in javascript code ofcourse)

Comment: I placed the line in the javascript and the input already uses id="address"

But it is not loading the data into the input field, am I missing something?

Comment: This needs trial and error, try to remove forms[0] and test, if still not working add name attribute for form and input and try document.formname.inputname.value=place.address, if still not working tell me which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest Firefox for Mac. I tried to remove forms[0] but that did not work. Also the other line did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: This html5 feature requires permission, did you allow it? also try to alert(place.address); there and see if you are getting the address

Comment: Yes I am allowing it every time when I refresh my browser, also     <p id="address"></p> shows me the data just to be sure.

I'm not a pro in javascript, wher do I need to put the alert? Under $('#address').html('Your address: '+place.address); ?

Comment: I just saw the <p> tag, why you use same id for p tag and input field? change them and try everything again, and yes put the alert there

Comment: THANK YOU HESHAM IT WORKS!
I added a name to the form and used the "document.formname.inputname.value=place.address" line. Thanks a lot

Comment: You welcome, I will edit the answer as the one it worked with you, good luck in your project!